# Is there a simple way to get the JavaScript output in Java (using Eclipse)?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

I'm trying to get the return value of a JavaScript function I've written. I can do it using a very complicated method involving listeners, but I'm wanting to use Eclipse's [Browser.evaluate](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html) method.

As a toy problem, I have the following code in a Java file:

```
Object result = this.browser.evaluate("new String(\"Hello World\")");
```

where this.browser is created in a class extending `org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart` in the overridden function `createPartControl`:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
  // Create the browser instance and have it 
  this.browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
  this.browser.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
      SomeEditor.this.getSite().getPage().activate(SomeEditor.this);
    }
  });
  new ErrorReporter(this.browser);
  this.browser.setUrl(Activator.getResourceURL("html/java-shim.html").toString());
  ...more stuff snipped...
}
```

However, instead of `result` being a Java String with the contents "Hello World", it's `null`. Am I using this method incorrectly, or is it broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return a value in JavaScript:

```
Object result = browser.evaluate("return 'Hello World'");
```

works for me.